# unable to read csv because of csv's quote char + delim + intermittent white space

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv which looks something like below.
I am unable to read this in pandas as desired as the seperator or delimiter (;) is not working properly OR the white space within a string is getting picked as delim.
Can you please advise.
I am trying to play with sep, delimiter,quotechar of pd_read_csv so far, but havent had much luck

```
201712;"201 906";"22222222";"No ABC";"XYZ";"Other Clients";"Go there ";"We are all here";"three words here";"Some place";"conti";"word";"22 222 222";"Tr";"Department ABC";"Proprietary Dept";"Proprietary Dept";"34    788";"-931";"-2 618.58";"31 238";"0";"0";"0";"31    464.48";"31 238"
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')`?

Comment: Yes tried this, but it isnt reading the way i would have expected. The some entries get split into the subsequent col, while some which are to be in separate cols end up in the single column

Comment: For this infact, all the entries end up going in the index of the dataframe

Comment: pls provide more details. what is your desired output? how is it not working properly?